# remap json objects and push them into one single array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm remapping JSON objects received from an API which works perfectly. The issue is instead of pushing into a single array `searchResultsReFormat`, in the console it reads the same line multiple times but with different values.

```
  searchResultsReFormat: any = [];
  this.searchResults.map(result => {
                const customer  = result.customer
                const meals = result.meals
                const newResults = [{
                  firstName : customer.firstName,
                  lastName : customer.lastName,
                  grade: this.gradeName,
                  meals: [meals]
                }]
                console.log(newResults)
                this.searchResultsReFormat = newResults
              })
```

[image]

but It all should have been grouped inside one single array `searchResultsReFormat` and when expanded, the data will be showing

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss what `.map` actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the object within  map and assign the map results to the array you want.

```
searchResultsReFormat: any = [];
  this.searchResultsReFormat = this.searchResults.map(result => {
                const customer  = result.customer
                const meals = result.meals
                return {
                  firstName : customer.firstName,
                  lastName : customer.lastName,
                  grade: this.gradeName,
                  meals: [meals]
                }                
              })
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is actually meant to **return a new array** by transforming **each value** according to the **callback** provided.

You don't need to push or do things, you just need to:

- Assign the result of map to the desired value.
- `return` inside the callback the transformed value.

// assignment here

```
this.searchResultsReFormat = this.searchResults.map(result => {
  //                                                ^--- callback here
  const customer  = result.customer;
  const meals = result.meals;
  const newResults = [{
    firstName : customer.firstName,
    lastName : customer.lastName,
    grade: this.gradeName,
    meals: [meals]
  }];
  return newResults; // <-- return here.
});
```